# Convert cps units to candelas / sq. meter

Tags: unit-conversion, luminosity, photometry

Spectra photometer was reported to measure luminance at given cps rate (counts per second). Is it enough data to know which luminance value it measured, given model and vendor are known?

Answer (score 0):

Counts per second or counts per minute are measurements of ionizing radiation whereas lumens are measurements of visible light. I am not sure if a comparison is possible. You might try contacting the manufacturer.